# How to select vector elements from each row of a 3D matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a 3D matrix for example a 1000-by-4-by-20 matrix A and I want to select one of the 1-by-20 vectors from each row of A according to a 1000-by-1 index vector B. This index vector includes numbers form 1 to 4.
Also, I do not want to use a for loop. 
How should I do that (with and/or without "sub2ind")?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the most elegant way, but it gets the job done:

```
[r,c,~]=size(A);
Q=reshape(A,r*c,[]);
P=sub2ind([r,c],[1:r]',B);
result=Q(P,:);
```

This will put each of the 1x1x20 vectors into the appropriate row in a 1000x20 result matrix. You can combine the last two lines if you want.

Here are the first 20 rows of a sample run with the vector `B` appended to the front to show which column we were supposed to take. The construction of `A` should be pretty obvious (first digit is the column number, next 3 are the row number - 1. All elements of the 1x1x20 vector are the same.)

```
  B       result
  2       2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000   2000
  1       1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001   1001
  4       4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002   4002
  4       4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003   4003
  3       3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004   3004
  4       4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005   4005
  3       3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006   3006
  1       1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007   1007
  3       3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008   3008
  4       4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009   4009
  2       2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010   2010
  4       4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011   4011
  3       3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012   3012
  2       2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013   2013
  4       4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014   4014
  4       4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015   4015
  1       1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016   1016
  2       2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017   2017
  4       4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018   4018
  3       3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019   3019
```

Comment: @ beaker, thank you, This is exactly what I wanted. But my overall code where I needed this code for is suddenly taking a looong time to execute. I'll post another question to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a another way using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
[r, c, t] = size(A);
result = A(bsxfun(@plus, (1:r).'+r*(B-1), (0:t-1)*r*c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Say the vector is called `A`.  You can index it like so:

```
A(1:1000,B,:)
```

Where index1 can range from 1 to 1000, and index2 can range from 1 to 4.
The colon selects everything at that index level.

Comment: I'm asking this in MATLAB (it's in the title and the tags).

Comment: My apologies, I think that was Mathematica and pandas indexing. Edited it.

Comment: Could you add a more detailed description of B? Is it two indices, one for the first dimension of A and one for the second dimension of A?

Comment: B is a vector of 1000 elements with values ranging from 1 to 4. So for each row I will need to extract one of the four 20-by-1 vectors of that row.

Comment: Try that. I don't have matlab at my disposal to test it out.

Comment: `A(1:1000,B,:)` gives you a `1000x1000x20` matrix.